# nasal passage or airway is too narrow

Tags: phrases

The doctor said his nasal 'passage' or 'airway' is too narrow, that's why he is easy to get stuffy nose.
Which word is correct and more common?

Comment: I think either is fine.

Comment: Did you look the words up in a dictionary? That might help.

Comment: This question should be closed because you haven't shown any evidence of research. There are many sites on the internet that will tell you how common words are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both terms are correct, while *airway* is broader and *nasal passage* would be more specific. I have moved the quotation marks to inclued *passage* to clarify this question. Let me know if I am wrong in doing so.  What follows might help:    I breath through my airway whenever I take a breath.  I breath through my nasal passage when I breath through my nose.  When I breath through my mouth, my airway barely includes my nasal passages.  If I breathed through an endotracheal tube, my airway would be my trachea.  In short, the answer to you question is a moving target.  Your doctor seems to be using the terms without enough context to provide a better answer to your question.